# Adding layers to project from processing tool in QGIS 3

Tags: layers, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to add some layers created during a process to a project.

There seems nothing to be added (TOC empty) but when I close QGIS it says:

> This project includes one or more layers as temporary draft. This
> layers are not saved at the disc and...

Or something like that (just my own translation)

I defined the layer as:

```py
vl_layerPG = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "vl_layerPG", "memory")
```

Filled with some data and then:

```py
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl_layerPG, True)
```

But this is not added to the TOC, almost visible.

I tried without `True` first as shown at the PyQGIS cookbook, but It was the same result.

```py
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    dxf_file = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INPUT_FILE, context)

    current = 0       
    #self.generaCapaPlantaGeneral(datos)
    
    driverIn = ogr.GetDriverByName('DXF')
    dataSource = driverIn.Open(dxf_file, 0)
    dataSource.ExecuteSQL("SELECT * FROM entities WHERE Layer = 'PG-LP'")
    layerIn = dataSource.GetLayer()        
    n_records = layerIn.GetFeatureCount()    
    inFeature = layerIn.GetNextFeature()
    
    geometryPoly = ogr.BuildPolygonFromEdges(ogr.ForceToMultiLineString(inFeature.GetGeometryRef()), dfTolerance = 10)
    geometryPolyWkt = geometryPoly.ExportToWkt()
                   
    ml = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "PG_layer", "memory")
    pr = ml.dataProvider()
    pr.addAttributes([
        QgsField("ref",QVariant.String),
    ])
    
    attrib = []
    attrib.append(46)
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setAttributes(attrib)
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(geometryPolyWkt))
    
    pr.addFeatures([feat])
    ml.updateFields()
    
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(ml)
    ml.updateExtents()        
            
    return {self.MEM_OUTPUT:ml}
```

Comment: Can you share more detail from your code?

Comment: Maybe try without 'True': QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl_layerPG)

Comment: @pnz I edited the question adding the code.  I'm a little stuck on that, because if I tried the  command `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(ml)` at the python terminal It works as expected.

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to import your layers in processing?

Comment: No yet, there's the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I founded a solution:

I read that is not possible to add a new layer from  *processAlgorithm* anymore.

But you can add then after, at the  *postProcessAlgorithm*

```
def postProcessAlgorithm(self, context, feedback):
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.ml)
```

Comment: I didn't test, but I think that `ml` in `processAlgorithm` have to be `self.ml` (I mean `self.ml = QgsVecto....`) for this to work in `postProcessAlgorithm`.

Comment: Yes, that ml must be self.ml